# eigenvectors of a graph Laplacian VS Fourier basis

Tags: graph-theory, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, signal-analysis

Could you please illustrate the following statement: 
 ***the eigenvectors of a
graph Laplacian behave similarly to a Fourier basis, motivating
the development of graph-based Fourier analysis theory.***